# Get Id of left side table based on condition on right side table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have two tables "**Header**" and "**Request**".

Header table have following columns "**NewItemHeaderId**", "**HeaderStatus**"

Request table have following columns "**NewItemRequestid**", "**RequestStatus**", "**NewItemHeaderId**"

Table values as below using left join

```
NewItemHeaderId | HeaderStatus                      | NewItemRequestId | RequestStatus
1147             MRD - Standardizer Pending          3351               MRD - Standardizer Pending
1148             TPSP - QC Pending                   3352               TPSP - QC Pending
1148             TPSP - QC Pending                   3353               TPSP - QC Pending
1149             TPSP - QC Pending                   3354               MRD - Standardizer Pending
1149             TPSP - QC Pending                   3355               MRD - Standardizer Pending
```

I need to get NewItemHeaderId where following condition as below

- RequestStatus need to be " **MRD - Standardizer Pending**"
- HeaderStatus also need to be "**MRD - Standardizer Pending**"

form above example

NewItemHeaderId 1149 having two entry in Request table(3354,3355).

we need to check 3354 and 3355 RequestStatus will be "MRD - Standardizer Pending"

if both having same status then we need to check HeaderStatus it should be "MRD - Standardizer Pending" if not we need to get that NewItemHeaderId.

for example, the result will be as below

```
NewItemHeaderId
---------------
1149
```

1147 not show because both  RequestStatus and header status is "MRD - Standardizer Pending"

1148 not show because RequestStatus is not "MRD - Standardizer Pending"

In the above table, HeaderStatus  will be "MRD - Standardizer Pending" for 1149 NewItemHeaderId

it will return null.

above table sql query as below

```
SELECT NIH.NewItemHeaderId,NIH.TPSPStatus AS 'Header Status', 
NIR.NewItemRequestId,NIR.Status AS RequesStatus
FROM NewItemHeader NIH
LEFT JOIN NewItemRequest NIR ON NIR.NewItemHeaderId = NIH.NewItemHeaderId
```

Comment: What is the real question/issue? When reading this I get the impression you know how to solve it yourself.

Comment: This question is self-contradictory and doesn't make any sense.  You say one of the conditions is that HeaderStatus = "MRD - ..." and then the only HeaderID that has that status you say it can't be that one.   How can you say that 1149 meets your requirement when it doesn't have the required Header Status??

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should add conditions as

```
SELECT NIH.NewItemHeaderId,NIH.TPSPStatus AS 'Header Status', 
NIR.NewItemRequestId,NIR.Status AS RequesStatus
FROM NewItemHeader NIH
LEFT JOIN NewItemRequest NIR ON NIR.NewItemHeaderId = NIH.NewItemHeaderId
WHERE NIH.TPSPStatus = 'MRD - Standardizer Pending' 
AND NIR.Status = 'MRD - Standardizer Pending'
```